# JavaScript / JQuery : Enable only some checkboxes and disable the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, twig

I'm not very skilled in js so i'm asking for help.

I have a list of [commercial plans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGExY.png) and a bunch of checkboxes and radio buttons.

When I select a plan with the radio, I want to disable checkboxes from the other plans.

Here's a piece of the dom :

```
{% for plan in plans %}
    <div class="row alert alert-info">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div>{{ plan['name'] }}</div>
            <div>{{ plan['description'] }}</div>
            <div>{{ plan['recurring_price'] }} €</div>
            <div>{{ plan['interval_unit'] }}</div>
            <div><br/></div>
            <div style="padding-left: 20px">
                {% for addon in plan.addons %}
                    {% if addon['type'] == 'recurring' %}
                        <div>{{ addon['name'] }}</div>
                        <div>{{ addon['description'] }}</div>
                        <div>{{ addon['price_brackets'][0]['price'] }} €</div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="{{ addon['addon_code'] }}" class="checkboxAddon" value="{{ addon['addon_code'] }}"> : Choose addon
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="choosePlan" id="{{ plan['plan_code'] }}" value="{{ plan['plan_code'] }}"> : Choose plan
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

I already thought of possible ways to do that with classes and DOM traversing but nothing elegant comes to mind.

Thanks to all of you that will take the time to reply.

Comment: It'll be very helpful if you can provide output HTML or a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work;

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('change', '.row .radio :radio', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $plan = $this.closest('.row'),
            $otherPlans = $('.row').not($plan);
        $plan.find(':checkbox').prop('disabled', false);
        $otherPlans.find(':checkbox').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: `prop('disabled',true)` (or `false`) not `prop('disabled','disabled')`. See: http://api.jquery.com/prop

Comment: Yeah, it's like you said in the documentation but modern browsers interprets `'disabled'` as `true` and `''` as `false`. Anyways, thanks for pointing out. :)